# how to give a post variable to php without reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to give php a simple variable from a text-box on a different page, without reloading it. I have heard that you need ajax to do it, but i am not sure on how to do that. I don't know how to use ajax so I just need an example.

thanks

Comment: simplest way: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You should really first try something and if it does not work `SO` is a great place to ask where u went wrong.

Comment: If you show little-to-no effort in helping yourself, few people here will put for any effort to help you either.  If all you want is an example, Google will provide plenty of those.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ( http://jquery.com/ ) is a nice javascript library that can handle this. Look at the .post function ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ ) this is commonly used for ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do with javascript, but upto now jQuery is the solution.

```
    $.ajax ({
            type:'post',
            url:'yourpage.php',
            success: function(response.trim()) {

                                               }
    data: $("#bidform").serialize();
           });
```